# Compare datevalue with today

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to select data when datevalue < than today, but the `where` condition that I make is not working, it always shows the value even that not right.

This is the query design table database  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgM3n.png

This is the query

```
SELECT *
FROM iu_trdetail_peminjaman 
WHERE CONVERT(char(10),dt_tgl_pinjam,110) <= CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
and dt_id_detailpeminjaman  = @p1
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? These are two different DBMS. From your query I assume SQL Server, so I've removed the `mysql` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the datetimes to strings in order to compare only the date part. But mistakenly you compare format 110 ('mm-dd-yyyy') with 126 ('yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm'). You'd have to compare format 23 ('yyyy-mm-dd') for both dates to make this work, because this format only contains the date part and has an appropriate sort order.

A better option is to convert the datetime you get with `GETDATE` to a `DATE`. Add a day, so to be able to ask for `yourdate < tomorrow (at midnight)`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM iu_trdetail_peminjaman 
WHERE dt_tgl_pinjam < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
and dt_id_detailpeminjaman  = @p1;
```